# Finding the length of longest string

Tags: python

I have just started to learn how to use python. A part of my exercise is to find the length of longest string in texts, defined as 'box' in the following case:

```
def file(box):
  maxlen=0
  f=box.splitlines()
  for i in f:
    if len(i)>=maxlen:
      maxlen=len(i)
    return maxlen

print file("""abcd efgh ijkl 
on different lines

I""")
```

In this case, I get number 14, instead of 18, which is the correct answer...can please somebody help me to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't get anything, because `file()` doesn't return anything. You'll print `None` instead.

Comment: Your code works just fine, if you added a return statement. What is the *real* code you are running?

Comment: Ok, I have added return maxlen, but the number is not right, returning 14.

Comment: What do you mean by 'real code'?

Comment: You return too early.. The code as posted, wasn't complete, and I assumed that your `return` statement was correctly placed. Now we know it isn't.

Comment: See the problem now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You've indented your return statement too much:

```
for i in f:
  if len(i)>=maxlen:
    maxlen=len(i)
  return maxlen
```

At the moment, you're telling it to `return` on every iteration of the loop, which means only the first line is returned. Move the return statement outside the loop:

```
for i in f:
  if len(i)>=maxlen:
    maxlen=len(i)
return maxlen
```

...and it should work.